# WooCommerce Product Category on Checkout Page

Tags: woocommerce

I want to show product category name in checkout order review table.Please let me know any needed changes applying here.

Review attached screenshot: http://nimb.ws/XHsQ5l

Thanks.

Comment: Modify the template called review-order.php in the checkout directory of the templates folder.

Comment: I will try to modify template called in review-order.php but we can't get it. If you know the modify code for how to get product category name please let me know.
B'coz i will find and try this in last 2 days but we can't do it.

Comment: Use the get_the_category() function to get the product categories. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/

Comment: We have try this but get the **array()** not category name.

Comment: Also  @AndrewSchultz the category name display in order details page. Here we have attached screenshot please review that and provide me the best solutions.
Screenshot: http://nimb.ws/l12xNB

Comment: The function get_the_category() will return an array of WP_Term objects which you can then get the category name from.

Comment: Ok thanks @AndrewSchultz